# Try to run flutter app after install speech-to-text package in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, kotlin, speech-to-text

```
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (306, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (307, 16): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (464, 22): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (467, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (476, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (483, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (486, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (490, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (491, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (492, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (494, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (495, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (498, 63): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String defined in kotlin
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (500, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (502, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (503, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (506, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (507, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (509, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (514, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (516, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (650, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (850, 13): Unresolved reference: run
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (851, 24): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (858, 13): Unresolved reference: run
e: /Users/subashkhatri/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/speech_to_text-6.6.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/SpeechToTextPlugin.kt: (859, 24): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/subashkhatri/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0be4579c3b0d57b8d268f0bc967fbf72/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.23.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':speech_to_text:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /Users/subashkhatri/Development/sathi/android/build.gradle:                         │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

NOTE: I already update Kotline version to latest but still it show error
Please Help ...

I already upgrade Kotline version.